# FFPLAY How Display at Screen Coordinates

Tags: coordinates

In a BAT file I have a complex filter chain which ends with `-f nut - | ffplay -`. The display location is center of the screen. I wish the size to be X and Y at location TOP it to be `-x 960 -left 950 -top 30`.

How do I add the coordinates to the example script?

```
ffmpeg -i %1 -vf scale=iw:-1 -f nut - | ffplay -
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ffmpeg -i %1 -vf scale=iw:-1 -f nut - | ffplay -x 960 -left 950 -top 30 -
```

The attributes must be end with space and dash  `-`.